# OPTIMIZE UNION SQL QUERY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I believe it is possible optimize this sql-server query. I have tried using an OUTER JOIN without result. Would anyone be able to help me optimise this query?

```
SELECT '1' AS CodigoEmpresa,
       T0.CodigoAlmacen,
       '' AS CodigoUbicacion,
       T0.CodigoArticulo,
       T0.Partida,
       CAST(T0.Unidades - ISNULL(T1.Unidades, 0) AS float) AS Unidades,
       T0.FechaCaduca
FROM dbo.ERP_Stock_Entrada_FINAL AS T0
LEFT JOIN dbo.ERP_Stock_Salida_FINAL AS T1 ON T0.CodigoArticulo = T1.CodigoArticulo
AND T0.Partida = T1.Partida
AND T0.CodigoAlmacen = T1.CodigoAlmacen
UNION
SELECT '1' AS CodigoEmpresa,
       T0.CodigoAlmacen,
       '' AS CodigoUbicacion,
       T0.CodigoArticulo,
       T0.Partida,
       CAST(ISNULL(T1.Unidades,0)-T0.Unidades AS FLOAT) AS Unidades,
       T0.Fechacaduca
FROM ERP_Stock_Salida_Final AS T0
LEFT JOIN dbo.ERP_Stock_Entrada_FINAL AS T1 ON T0.CodigoArticulo = T1.CodigoArticulo
AND T0.Partida = T1.Partida
AND T0.CodigoAlmacen = T1.CodigoAlmacen
```

Comment: Please have a bash at formatting this question to be readable

Comment: Did you actually mean `union` as opposed to `union all`?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Optimize in what way? Does the query what you want it to do, but you consider it too slow? With such questions you should show your table structures anyway. Is CodigoArticulo unique in any of the tables?

Comment: Umm, my eyes aren't what they used to be, but as far as I can tell, the only difference between the two branches of the `UNION` is that the 6th column (Unidades) is `CAST(T0.Unidades - ISNULL(T1.Unidades, 0) AS float)` in the first branch and reversed in the second branch.  Is this correct?  Because if so then it should be easy to optimize.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, you want a `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT '1' AS CodigoEmpresa,
       COALESCE(T0.CodigoAlmacen, T1.CodigoAlmacen) as CodigoAlmacen
       '' AS CodigoUbicacion,
       COALESCE(T0.CodigoArticulo, T1.CodigoArticulo) as CodigoArticulo
       COALESCE(T0.Partida, T1.Partida) as Partida
       CAST(COALESCE(T0.Unidades, 0) - COALESCE(T1.Unidades, 0) AS float) AS Unidades,
       COALESCE(T0.FechaCaduca, T1.FechaCaduca) as FechaCaduca
FROM dbo.ERP_Stock_Entrada_FINAL T0 FULL JOIN
     dbo.ERP_Stock_Salida_FINAL T1
     ON T0.CodigoArticulo = T1.CodigoArticulo AND
        T0.Partida = T1.Partida AND
        T0.CodigoAlmacen = T1.CodigoAlmacen;
```